# Conversion Tracking in SFMC - can't find answers

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion, goals

There are several threads but very few answers to this.

Does SFMC provide a simple js code to copy and paste on the landing page or 3rd party system like Tune in order to receive and report on conversions from email launched through SFMC?

The documentation here is elaborate but JS script examples do not work:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/conversion_tracking/

Answer (score 1):

What about [Web & Mobile Analytics](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/web_and_mobile_analytics/)?  There's some documentation on [Purchase Tracking](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/collect_code/install_collect_code/track_conversion/) also.

[image: Web & Mobile Analytics screenshot]

It can be enabled without cost, I believe.

I've never actually seen Conversion Tracking in the wild.

Comment: Thank you Adam.  We have that enabled.  Having hard time tracking conversions though:  Does the Collect Code need to be installed on the landing page, and then ADDITIONALLY this conversion script on the order confirmation?

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/collect_code/install_collect_code/track_conversion/

We tested it this way and the conversions are not carrying over.